# Rcpp: Is a wrapping class the only way to preserve fundamental types pointed to by Xptr?

Tags: c++, r, pointers, rcpp

I have a fair bit of experience with R, but am only now getting down to the business of learning C++, so I beg forgiveness for any ensuing stupidity....

Given the following test.cpp file:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <string>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;

XPtr< double > getPtr(NumericVector x) {
  double i;
  i = REAL(x)[0];
  XPtr< double > p(&i, false);
  XPtr<double> checkP(p);
  double checkV = *checkP;
  cout << "Values within getPtr scope:" << endl;
  cout << "Pointer address " << hex << checkP << endl;
  cout << "Pointer value " << checkV << endl;
  return p;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void testPtr(NumericVector x){ 
  XPtr<double> p(getPtr(x));
  cout << "Values outside of getPtr scope:" << endl;
  cout << "Pointer address " << hex << p << endl;
  cout << "Pointer value " << *p << endl;
  return;
}
```

The following R snippet demonstrates that the value pointed to by the Xptr "disappears" outside the getPtr function.

```
> library(Rcpp)
> Rcpp::sourceCpp(file="test.cpp")
> 
> test <- c(35,28,16,52)
> testPtr(test)
Values within getPtr scope:
Pointer address 0x7ffd3763d790
Pointer value 35
Values outside of getPtr scope:
Pointer address 0x7ffd3763d790
Pointer value 6.95277e-310
```

But of course! Since that value is out of scope, this is expected behavior.

Alternatively, if I wrap the value in a class and use `new`, the object persists and I can retrieve my value outside the scope of the called function:

```
class Wrap {
public:
  Wrap(double x) {
    i = x;
  }
  double i;
};

XPtr< Wrap > getPtrW(NumericVector x) {
  double i;
  i = REAL(x)[0];
  Wrap* w = new Wrap(i);
  XPtr< Wrap > p(w, true);
  return p;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void testWrappedPtr(NumericVector x){ 
  XPtr<Wrap> wp(getPtrW(x));
  Wrap w = *(wp);
  cout << "Wrapped value " << w.i << endl;
  return;
}
```

Then this demonstrates that the value persists as desired:

```
> testWrappedPtr(test)
Wrapped value 35
```

My questions (at last) are these: (1) Is this (i.e. wrapping in a class) the only way to hang on to values of variables that are fundamental types and not malloc'd or new'd and (2) if not, are any of the alternative ways "better" or "preferred"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is pretty long already yet I don't get the feeling I know what your real question is.  You'd never do `XPtr<double>` as you have `NumericVector` for `double`.  So I am unsure what it is you need help with.

Comment: In the actual use case, I need to keep track of a CUdeviceptr which apparently is typdef'd as unsigned int, which depending on architecture could be the dreaded unsigned long long int I take it. Since I already have the value on the C side it seemed simplest just to keep track of it via Xptr. The solution above works fine but I wondered if maybe I am approaching it All Wrong. Which remains a possibility.

Comment: Ok. That's better -- we do use XPtr for things R does not know about, and/or cannot map, ie database and other handles.  Do you need to bring it back to R?  Else you could just have a class in the C++ file ...

Comment: Yes, it needs to come back to R so the user can load up data on the GPU and then call one or more kernels one or more times passing in the pointers to the data in appropriate order to match the kernel signatures. (Yes, RCUDA might meet all our use cases but I try to keep the black boxes in my mind to a minimum.)